# trigonometry calculator in C#

Tags: c#, math

I'm trying to make a calculator for trigonometry.

This is my form https://gyazo.com/6faecac18159d84b33497e06d864aa3d

When I input 3 numbers it should get the right result. 
Picture of actual result = https://gyazo.com/aa65ab502c0337ece0753b72029fa34a

But I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my code.

This is my code

```
            double B = Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text);
            double C = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            double side_A = 180 - B - C;
            string ConverterForA = Convert.ToString(side_A);
            textBox2.Text = ConverterForA;

            double calculatorForb = Math.Cos(C * (Math.PI / 180));
            string Converterforb = Convert.ToString(calculatorForb);
            textBox3.Text = Converterforb;

            double calculatorForc = Math.Sin(C * (Math.PI / 180));
            string ConverterForc = Convert.ToString(calculatorForc);
            textBox6.Text = ConverterForc;
```

The sides for the triangle

```
        //double C = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        //double A = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
        //double b = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
        //double a = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
        //double B = Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text);
        //double c = Convert.ToDouble(textBox6.Text);
```

as you can see the result is all mixed up. I put in 10,50 and 80

Comment: You need to tell us what is happening so that we aren't poking around in the dark. Are you getting exceptions? Bad results?

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is that you are having with this code?

Comment: Hi, Is your problem related to math/logic?

Comment: @BrootsWaymb , what exactly are you trying to compute?

Comment: @ShaiAharoni - Did you mean to tag OP in that comment instead? I'm not trying to compute anything, just get clarification.

Comment: Im getting the wrong result "udrengerForb" should be 8,682409
And "udrengerForc" should be 49,24039
But insted im getting
udrengerForC = 0,984807753012208
udrengerFor B = 0,17364817766693

Comment: @Belcookies - Post the details into the questions itself, not as comments so that they are more easily accessible and help out your question as a whole.

Comment: A picture of my form https://gyazo.com/6faecac18159d84b33497e06d864aa3d

Comment: No errors in your code. May be the algorithm is wrong

Comment: Please use names in your code that are more descriptive than "textbox1" or "a". Your future self will thank you for it

Comment: You need to multiplie your `cos` and `sin` with `hypotenuse (υποτείνουσα)` to get the side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having a hard time following your variable names and what is meant to match with what and consequently have renamed - I suggest you take a look at this and make them meaningful to you. However the following works (assuming that care is taken with data entry - you will obviously need to add some validation at some stage.

```
double anglec = Convert.ToDouble(text_anglec.Text);
double angleb = Convert.ToDouble(text_angleb.Text);
//double anglea = Convert.ToDouble(text_anglea.Text);
double length1 = Convert.ToDouble(text_length1.Text);
//double length2 = Convert.ToDouble(text_length2.Text);
//double length3 = Convert.ToDouble(text_length3.Text);


double anglea = 180 - angleb - anglec;       
text_anglea.Text = anglea.ToString();

double length2 = length1 * Math.Sin(anglea * (Math.PI / 180));
text_length2.Text = length2.ToString();

double length3 = length1 *  Math.Cos(anglea * (Math.PI / 180));
text_length3.Text = length3.ToString();
```